# Result from processing audio signal with Goertzel algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, signal-processing, goertzel-algorithm

I made a little signal processing app. It processes audio signal (morse code) on certain frequency with Goerztel algorithm. Application saves temporary file to the filesystem and after recording is finished, starts to detect signals. Now I got the result with bunch of magnitudes.

I don't really know what to read from those magnitudes. How can I decode the morse code from those magnitudes? How can I read them? Tried to find references, but nowhere is explained what is the result and how to read it.

**EDIT:**

My morse code application is made with Delphi and uses Windows Beep function to send signals with certain frequency. I'm using 1200 Hz for signals. Also pauses between signals and words and morse beeps are like wikipedia described. All is accurate.

Goertzel.java:

```
 public class Goertzel {

        private float samplingRate;
        private float targetFrequency;
        private int n;

        private double coeff, Q1, Q2;
        private double sine, cosine;

        public Goertzel(float samplingRate, float targetFrequency, int inN) {
            this.samplingRate = samplingRate;
            this.targetFrequency = targetFrequency;
            n = inN;

            sine = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (targetFrequency / samplingRate));
            cosine = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (targetFrequency / samplingRate));
            coeff = 2 * cosine;
        }

        public void resetGoertzel() {
            Q1 = 0;
            Q2 = 0;
        }

        public void initGoertzel() {
            int k;
            float floatN;
            double omega;

            floatN = (float) n;
            k = (int) (0.5 + ((floatN * targetFrequency) / samplingRate));
            omega = (2.0 * Math.PI * k) / floatN;
            sine = Math.sin(omega);
            cosine = Math.cos(omega);
            coeff = 2.0 * cosine;

            resetGoertzel();
        }

        public void processSample(double sample) {
            double Q0;

            Q0 = coeff * Q1 - Q2 + sample;
            Q2 = Q1;
            Q1 = Q0;
        }

        public double[] getRealImag(double[] parts) {
            parts[0] = (Q1 - Q2 * cosine);
            parts[1] = (Q2 * sine);

            return parts;
        }

        public double getMagnitudeSquared() {
            return (Q1 * Q1 + Q2 * Q2 - Q1 * Q2 * coeff);
        }
    }
```

SoundCompareActivity.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class SoundCompareActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE = 8000; // at least 2 times
                                                                // higher than sound
                                                                // frequency,
        private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
        private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

        private AudioRecord recorder = null;
        private int bufferSize = 0;
        private Thread recordingThread = null;
        private boolean isRecording = false;

        private Button startRecBtn;
        private Button stopRecBtn;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            startRecBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            stopRecBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            startRecBtn.setEnabled(true);
            stopRecBtn.setEnabled(false);

            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE,
                    RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

            startRecBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("SOUNDCOMPARE", "Start Recording");

                    startRecBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    stopRecBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    stopRecBtn.requestFocus();

                    startRecording();
                }
            });

            stopRecBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("SOUNDCOMPARE", "Stop recording");

                    startRecBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    stopRecBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    startRecBtn.requestFocus();

                    stopRecording();
                }
            });
        }

        private void startRecording() {
            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

            recorder.startRecording();

            isRecording = true;

            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    writeAudioDataToTempFile();
                }
            }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

            recordingThread.start();
        }

        private String getTempFilename() {
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "tempaudio");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            File tempFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "signal.raw");

            if (tempFile.exists())
                tempFile.delete();

            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "signal.raw");
        }

        private void writeAudioDataToTempFile() {
            byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
            String filename = getTempFilename();
            FileOutputStream os = null;

            try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int read = 0;

            if (os != null) {
                while (isRecording) {
                    read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                    if (read != AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                        try {
                            os.write(data);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private void deleteTempFile() {
            File file = new File(getTempFilename());

            file.delete();
        }

        private void stopRecording() {
            if (recorder != null) {
                isRecording = false;

                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();

                recorder = null;
                recordingThread = null;
            }

            new MorseDecoder().execute(new File(getTempFilename()));    
        }
    }
```

MorseDecoder.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class MorseDecoder extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void> {
    private FileInputStream is = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File... files) {
        int index;
        //double magnitudeSquared; 
        double magnitude; 

        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        Goertzel g = new Goertzel(8000, 1200, bufferSize);
        g.initGoertzel();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(files[i]);

                while(is.read(data) != -1) {
                    ShortBuffer sbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
                    short[] audioShorts = new short[sbuf.capacity()];
                    sbuf.get(audioShorts);

                    float[] audioFloats = new float[audioShorts.length];

                    for (int j = 0; j < audioShorts.length; j++) {
                        audioFloats[j] = ((float)audioShorts[j]) / 0x8000;
                    }

                    for (index = 0; index < audioFloats.length; index++) { 
                        g.processSample(data[index]); 
                    }

                    magnitude = Math.sqrt(g.getMagnitudeSquared());


                    Log.d("SoundCompare", "Relative magnitude = " + magnitude);

                    g.resetGoertzel();
                }

                is.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Notices some bugs in processing samples. Changed code in while loop.

```
while(is.read(data) != -1) {
                    ShortBuffer sbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
                    short[] audioShorts = new short[sbuf.capacity()];
                    sbuf.get(audioShorts);

                    float[] audioFloats = new float[audioShorts.length];

                    for (int j = 0; j < audioShorts.length; j++) {
                        audioFloats[j] = ((float)audioShorts[j]) / 0x8000;
                    }

                    for (index = 0; index < audioFloats.length; index++) { 
                        g.processSample(audioFloats[index]); 

                        magnitude = Math.sqrt(g.getMagnitudeSquared());
                        Log.d("SoundCompare", "Relative magnitude = " + magnitude);
                    }

                    //magnitude = Math.sqrt(g.getMagnitudeSquared());


                    //Log.d("SoundCompare", "Relative magnitude = " + magnitude);

                    g.resetGoertzel();
                }
```

Regards,
evilone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of your [Goertzel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) will increase when a tone within its passband is present, and then decrease when the tone is removed. In order to detect pulses of a tone, e.g. morse code, you need some kind of threshold detector on the output of the filter which will just give a boolean value for "tone present" / "tone not present" on a sample-by-sample basis. Try plotting the output values and it should be obvious once you see it in graphical form.

Comment: Is there any examples around how exactly to do that?

Comment: @evilone: did you *read* the Wikipedia page ? There are a couple of links to articles on DTMF decoding using Goertzel in the References section near the bottom of the page. DTMF decoding is very similar to morse decoding, in that you need to detect tone start/stop times so you should be able to use the same techniques.

Comment: i think, there's no pattern. tried to plot some example tones. Maybe I'm using Goertzel filter wrong. Is there some implementations in Java?

Comment: Maybe you should start a new question and post your existing Goertzel code so that we can all see if you're doing it right ?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code - to debug this I'd be inclined to dump out the input signal and the Goertzel output, verify that the input signal does contain bursts of a 1200 Hz sine wave and then compare the output of the filter for quiet periods versus tone periods.

Comment: Hm, if I record this dump file wihout sending signals then magintudes look the same as with morse beeping. Is there any visualization tools? Or how can view those sine waves?

Comment: For a small number of samples (< 32k samples) I would typically use a spreadsheet such as Excel to visualize the data. For larger amounts of data I would use MATLAB or a free equivalent such as Octave: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: how do I format the timeline in excel chart? and do I insert usual line chart?

Comment: If you have time values (or sample numbers) in the first column then you can do an X-Y (scatter) plot, otherwise just do a normal line plot.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each magnitude in my example is for one sample?

Comment: Yes, the Goertzel filter is updated with every new input sample, so if you have N = 1024 samples in then you will get 1024 (filtered) samples out

Comment: hmm, but in my case I think this is wrong at the code, because I'm printing magnitude out in a while loop not in the for loop that processes samples. I think I print out the magnitudes after every N samples.

Comment: Well so long as you are *updating* the filter on every sample and doing something with the output value (either storing it or processing it in some way) then that's OK. If not then yes you would need to fix that.

Comment: Also I notice that, I'm processing wrong array - the byte array not the float one. Ok, I'm updating my code in question, please look if it's correct now.

Comment: It looks OK to me but I don't do Java and I don't have a lot of time to look at it in detail - does the output look more reasonable now ?

Comment: Before the values were like 1000.42342342342 and 634.23423423423 etc. Now they have 0.00123423423 and 9.34234234, but somehow signal is more readable

Comment: OK - you should see some correlation between filter output values and whether the input tone is present or not.

Comment: Most of the time the values are between zero and 1, then it's starting to grow slowly. And grows to 3-4, sometimes 9. Then values are going down again between 0 and 1. Something like that. If I have sampling rate 8000, does it mean that 1 sec sound generates 8000 rows of data?

Comment: Yes, 1 second @ 8 kHz sample rate - 8000 samples. If a morse "dash" is say 300 ms long then you'd expect to see a high output value for around 2400 samples.

Comment: Comments are not the place for extended discussions. Try [chat] or perhaps asking a follow-up question. You might even have a look at the new [dsp.se] site.

Comment: True - I did actually suggest starting a new question. We can move to chat if there is any further discussion needed.

Answer (score 0):

Plot the signal magnitudes on a graph versus time (some CW decoding apps for the PC do this in real-time).  Now figure out what the graph for each Morse code symbol should look like.  Then study some pattern matching algorithms.  If there is enough noise present, you may want to try some statistical pattern matching methods.

Here's the [Wikipedia link for proper Morse Code timing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Representation.2C_timing_and_speeds).